# Link Form Data to Another Form Upon Submit

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I would appreciate any help on this subject as I've been at standoff for a few weeks now.

Essentially I'm using Google Forms to take attendance at multiple events for an organization. The initial form allows an officer to submit the name of the new event along with some other information. This form exports all of it's data to a Google Sheet. The following form allows any member to update their attendance if it was put in wrong, and then exports that data to a different sheet from the first form.

The problem that I'm having is with reading in all of the event names as options on a multiple choice grid for the second form. I have it setup using submitFormFunction() and it essentially rereads all events each time the form is submitted, but when it does that it exports every events as a completely new column on the spreadsheet, even if there is already a column for that event.

I would like it to only add the new event to the multiple choice grid whenever the first form is submitted so that the columns on the sheet that the second form exports to will stay the same and only one new column will be added per new event.

I'm currently using the Add-On FormRanger to populate the options. Thanks in advance for any advice!

Here's the code that I currently have in the script editor for the second form:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1eTE_ZDLJjzLmzwjC-P6LBCFhNd_pgVndfZkUNKLFXkM");

function submitFormFunction(e) {

  //Select spreadsheet and gather response data
  var items = e.response.getItemResponses(); 
  var responses = {}; 
  for (var i=0; i<item.length; i++) {
    responses[i] = items[i].getResponse(); 
  }

  //Export data to sheet
  var responseRow = [];
  responseRow.append(responses[0]);
  for (var j=2; j<(item.length-1); j++) {
    responseRow.append(responses[j]); 
  }

  return;
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful to get more answers, if you include some piece of code rather complete paragraph

Comment: I added it to the original post, thank you for pointing that out!